# Include custom fonts in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have a question about generating PDFs with **wkhtmltopdf**. I know it's possible to use custom fonts in my html. But I think it's required that the operating system viewing the pdf has installed these fonts. Correct?

My question is whether it's possible to include these fonts in the PDF? So when the PDF is generated I can send it to a print office to print 50 copies. And they see the pdf exactly the same as I, without having these fonts installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible.
It's called "embedding a font" in pdf lingo.
Most pdf generation libraries should support this.

Pdf comes in different flavors (standards). One of the standards pdf/A is meant for long term storage (the A stands for archiving). The idea being that the document look and feel should be preserved as much as possible. In order to achieve this without depending on the operating system (and the fonts it may be shipped with), it is required that the fonts are embedded to fulfill the pdf/A standard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A

I don't know how to do this in the library you are using. But I do know it's possible with iText.

This is a great tutorial on it, which aside from giving you more information about iText, will also illustrate the problem with custom fonts in a very visual way.

https://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/using-fonts-pdf-and-itext

Comment: I'm using [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle). That's using wkhtmltopdf.